# AWS SDK - change autoscaling group update policy

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, autoscaling

I've an autoscaling group on AWS and I'd like to change its update policy to get rolling update.

I've tried

```
var autoScaling = new AWS.AutoScaling(awsConfig);
autoScaling.updateAutoScalingGroup({
    AutoScalingGroupName: <some name>,
    UpdatePolicy: {
        AutoScalingReplacingUpdate: {
            WillReplace: true,
        },
    }
})
```

But this is failing with:

```
{ [UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'UpdatePolicy' found in params]
  message: 'Unexpected key \'UpdatePolicy\' found in params',
  code: 'UnexpectedParameter',
  time: Tue Nov 08 2016 22:15:42 GMT-0800 (PST) }
```

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/AutoScaling.html#updateAutoScalingGroup-property - The documentaions doesn't list `UpdatePolicy` as one of the valid parameters for this function.

Comment: What are you trying to change? Most Likely you'll need a new Launch Config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UpdatePolicy is a feature of AWS CloudFormation. It is not a feature found in the AWS API itself so none of the SDKs will have it.  This is the documentation from CF.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-updatepolicy.html

Comment: That's right. So can I just create a cloud formation, and attach it to the autoscaling group and that's it? I could not find out how to create a cloud formation that uses an existing scaling group

Comment: I am not sure you need to go out of your way to use CF for this but that really depends on what you are trying to accomplish. Probably better for different question.

Comment: I'm attaching a new Launch Configuration to the autoScaling Group with a different image and I'd like this image to roll out and replace existing instances

Comment: Ah.. then yes, CF is a good option. But you will need to start from scratch which can be a lot of work.